# Why is only one instance of GlobalWindow used?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Look at this [example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/windowing/SessionWindowing.java):

```java
// We create sessions for each id with max timeout of 3 time units
DataStream<Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>> aggregated = source
        .keyBy(0)
        .window(GlobalWindows.create())
        .trigger(new SessionTrigger(3L))
        .sum(2);
```

Can anybody explain me why in this example are using one instance of `GlobalWindow` (created inside `GlobalWindows#assignWindows`)?

Seems like for any incoming event IDs should be created own window i.e. `Window(a)` for `a` event, `Window(b)` for `b` event, etc. because as I understand Flink are using instances of Window for associate corresponded events i.e. all `a` events should be associated with `Window(a)` for example. In this case only all `a` events associated with `Window(a)` will be passed to window function and processed together (in this example will be calculated count of event grouped by ID i.e. by `a`, `b`, etc.), but as you can see this example using one instance of `GlobalWindow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that Flink uses the `Window` instances to group elements together which belong to the same window. However, even before, the input stream is grouped according to the specified key. So internally Flink stores for each key a list of windows and their associated elements. This allows to use across multiple keys the same window instance.

To be more precise, internally you have a nested `Map<Window, Map<Key, List<Element>>` which stores for every pair of `Window` and `Key` the elements in a `List`.

The benefit of this approach is that the implementations of the windowing logic on a keyed stream and a non-keyed stream do not differ. For the latter case you simply set the key to a dummy value.

Comment: From the https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/windows.html , it says" A global windows assigner assigns all elements with the same key to the same single global window.", so if there are 10 different keys, it would generate  10 different global window ?

Comment: Semantically you will have for each key a different window. Implementation wise, the window instance is the same across all keys. The reason is that the window instance forms a composite key with the key value to uniquely identify the window elements.

Comment: This is just for global Windows, right? For the Time Windows, 10 different keys would have 10 separated different time window instances  even from the implementation  perspective ,right ?Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Till, also I have a puzzle, if  the window instance is the same across all keys for global window ,however one separated window instance for each different key for the time window from the implementation wise, why time window doesn't use the same strategy as the global window?

Comment: Because time windows are bound to a time interval (e.g. from 1:00 to 2:00 if you have hourly windows).

Comment: So it seems there is no way to combine the global Window trigger and time Window trigger together? Just as the issue mentioned in the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382329/can-we-combine-both-and-count-and-process-time-trigger-in-flink

Comment: I think it should be doable using Flink's trigger mechanism.

Comment: I got a solution by  using Flink's trigger mechanism from the following URL https://gist.github.com/shikhar/2cb9f1b792be31b7c16e  ,  as the comments mentioned it needs to "synchronize" the "onElement" and "onProcessingTime" functions ?