# Can we combine both and count and process time Trigger in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to make the Windows completed after the count reached 100 or every 5 seconds for the tumbling process time ? That is to say when the elements reached 100, trigger the Windows computation, however if the elements don't reache 100, but the time elapsed 5 seconds, it also trigger the Windows computation, just as the combination of the below two triggers:

.countWindow(100)

.window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no super simple way to do this with the current Flink API.

Your use case needs a combination of state (for counting), and a timer. You can either accomplish this with windows using a custom [Trigger](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html#triggers), or by using a [ProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/process_function.html).

For the approach with windows plus a custom trigger, looking at the [implementations](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/triggers) of ProcessingTimeTrigger and CountTrigger will be helpful, as you basically want to blend the two.

ProcessFunction is a lower-level building block that combines managed state with timers, which is exactly what you need, so this is probably easier, especially if you already know how to work with [Flink's managed state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state).

BTW, the [online Flink training](https://training.ververica.com) include materials for learning how to use ProcessFunctions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindly help, I would do some checking for your materials, and would response here if I have some difficulties.

Comment: I noticed that your example here http://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/dataStream/5-intro.html is different from the official example for the https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/process_function.html  for the function onTimer , there is timestamp == result.lastModified + XXX) in official example, however no  XXX in your example.

Comment: Also may I ask what's the ctx.timestamp() meaning ? Where is coming from and when it was assigned to the ctx? From the official example it seems ctx.timestamp()  changes per 60 seconds, is it a watermark?

Comment: In processElement, ctx.timestamp is the timestamp extracted from the stream element currently being processed. This might change with every call to processElement, or not, depending on what your stream looks like. The current watermark is available from ctx.timerService().currentWatermark(). The timestamps and watermarks come from your TimestampExtractor and WatermarkGenerator.

Comment: Thanks, yes, there are a couple of bugs in the slides. I'll fix them.

Comment: Thank you alpinegizmo, BTW, you mentioned that my requirement can be implemented by  custom trigger or ProcessFunction , and I notice there is a big difference for them,   it seems if I use ProcessFunction , I can implement it  by just managed state and without global window , however if I implement it by custom trigger, we need the global window, so why this happens? and  what's the relationship between  managed state and global\time window ?

Comment: ProcessFunction is a very convenient, low-level building block that simply combines managed state with timers. Internally, windows use the same managed state and timer services you can access via ProcessFunction, but managing the global window with a custom trigger and evictor is usually more trouble and not as flexible.

Comment: Much appreciate for your kindly help alpinegizmo